# Hacking to make ReflectionFactory work (Repackaging)

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I know that GAE is a very restrictive platform; and it restricts access to classes like the `sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory`

However, many library rely on these packages but is not allowed in the GAE platform. Now I tried to peek into the sun.reflect package and it seems most classes there have dependencies in the `java.lang.reflect` which I think most classes are white listed.

So if we can include these `sun.reflect` package and perhaps repackage it into some other name, I guess this could be a work around?

- Does renaming the black listed package will make it work with GAE?
- Are there any implementaton of sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory that has been tweaked to run in the GAE platform?
- What are the options for making this work?

**Update:**

Issues filed in the appengine issue tracking I found that is related to this:

https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=1877

However it seems to me that this request was never granted.

Here are other issues tracking items relating to this:

https://code.google.com/p/objenesis/issues/detail?id=12

Answer (score 1):

There are none. `ReflectionFactory` relies on `native` methods which are bound by loading a native library. Even if you copied the class into another name space, you would have to load the related library what should be even harder to accomplish than accessing the `ReflectionFactory`.